# Frattini Subgroup of p-Groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Letting $P$ be a $p$-group and $\Phi(P)$ be the Frattini subgroup of $P$ (the intersection of all maximal subgroups), the challenge is "Prove that $P/N$ is elementary abelian implies $\Phi(P)≤N$" (from Dummit and Foote 6.1.26b). The previous exercise has already established $P/\Phi(P)$ is elementary abelian since $P'≤\Phi(P)$ and $\langle~x^p~|~x∈P~\rangle≤\Phi(P)$.

The first step I took here was proving $P/N$ is elementary abelian if and only if $\langle~x^p,~P'~|~x∈P~\rangle ≤ N$, so it seemed natural to prove that $\Phi(P)=\langle~x^p,~P'~|~x∈P~\rangle$. I believe $\Phi(P)/P'=(P/P')^p$ (where $(P/P')^p$ is the image of the $p$-power map) would imply $\Phi(P)P'=\langle~x^p~|~x∈P~\rangle P'=\langle~x^p,~P'~|~x∈P~\rangle$, which would imply $\Phi(P)=\langle~x^p,~P'~|~x∈P~\rangle$ as desired, but I can't find much way to proceed further. The $\supseteq$ direction is clear, but I can't find the reverse containment. Am I going at all the right way about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd prove that if $P/N$ is elementary abelian, then $N$ is the intersection of the maximal subgroups of $G$ that contain it.

Answer (score 3):

A (huge) hint: prove that under the given hypothesis, we have that

$$\Phi(P)=P^p[P,P]$$

With the above, and with the part $\,P^p\le N\,$ that you almost got already,  what is left is $\,P'\le N\,$ , and the abelian part does this job.

Comment: @Feryll: In fact when $P/N$ is elementary abelian so it is a vector space over $\mathbb Z_p$

Comment: @DonAntonio Does $P^p$ need to be a group? Because the $p$-power map shouldn't necessarily be a homomorphism on an arbitrary $p$-group.

Comment: @Feryll, that's how the subgroup generated by all $p-$th power of elements of $\,P\,$  is usually denoted

Answer (score 1):

Lemma 1: [mesel](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1577200/1197554) Let $P$ be a finite $p$-group and $H\unlhd P$ so $P/H$ is elementary abelian. Then the Frattini subgroup $\Phi\left(P/H\right)=\left\{H\right\}\cong 1$.

Proof of Lemma 1: $P$ is a finite $p$-group and $P/H$ is elementary abelian so $P/H\cong Z_{p}\times\cdots\times Z_{p}$ with the appropriate number of factors in the direct product. Every subgroup obtained by replacing any single factor of $Z_{p}$ with the identity is maximal (see Theorem~6.1.1(5)) so it is evident that
\begin{align*}
            \Phi\left(P/H\right)\cong\left\{1\times\cdots\times 1\right\}\cong 1\cong\left\{H\right\}
        \end{align*}

Lemma 2: It is obvious that $\Phi\left(P\right)/\left(N\cap\Phi\left(P\right)\right)\leq\Phi\left(P/\left(N\cap\Phi\left(P\right)\right)\right)$.

Proof: Let $P^{p}=\left\{\left. x^{p}\right|\ x\in P\right\}$ and observe that both $P^{p}$ and $P^{\prime}$ are contained in $N\cap\Phi\left(P\right)$ so $P/\left(N\cap\Phi\left(P\right)\right)$ is elementary abelian. Then the lemmas imply
\begin{align*}
            \Phi\left(P\right)/\left(N\cap\Phi\left(P\right)\right)
            &\leq\Phi\left(P/\left(N\cap\Phi\left(P\right)\right)\right)
            \cong 1
        \end{align*}
so $\Phi\left(P\right)=N\cap\Phi\left(P\right)$. That is, $\Phi\left(P\right)\leq N$. Thus the result.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about my answer.
If a group is an elementary abelian group, then its Frattini subgroup is 1. (I am not sure about this part).
Now we assume that $x \in \Phi (P)$ and $x \notin N$. As a result, $xN \neq 1N $ and by the above statement, it couldn't be a nanogenerator. Thus, there exits a subgroup in $P /N$ that is in the format of $I/N$ ($N \subseteq I)$.

$$<xN,I / N> = P /N $$
This means that $<x,I>$ should contain at least one element in each $pN$ for all $p \in P$. We want to conclude that $<x,I>=P$, and this is a contradiction. For each $p \in P$, there exists $n \in N$:
$$ pn \in <x,I>$$
We know that $I$ should contains $N$. So, $\; p \in <x,P>$.