# If $\theta :G\rightarrow H$ is a surjective homomorphism, then $\theta(\Phi(G))\leq\Phi(H)$.

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, p-groups, frattini-subgroup

This is a claim when I try to solve another problem related to the Fratinni group of a p-group, and I saw an answer [Frattini subgroup of a finite elementary abelian $p$-group is trivial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577150/frattini-subgroup-of-a-finite-elementary-abelian-p-group-is-trivial). I am stuck at the second step where the author claims that If $\theta :G\rightarrow H$ is a surjective homomorphism, then $\theta(\Phi(G))\leq\Phi(H)$, where $\Phi(G)$ and $\Phi(H)$ are the Frattini subgroup of $G$ and $H$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

This follows from the [correspondence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem_(group_theory)).

Let $h \not \in \Phi(H)$. Then for some maximal subgroup $M \leq H$, we must have $h \not \in M$ (since $\Phi$ is the intersection of the maximal subgroups). But then any preimage $\theta^{-1} h \not \in \theta^{-1} M$, which is a maximal subgroup by correspondence. So $\theta^{-1}h \not \in \Phi(G)$.

Taking contrapositives gives the desired claim: $\theta [ \Phi(G) ] \leq \Phi(H)$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks a lot. There is one question about the preimage of a maximal subgroup, why does it have to be maximal in G. I can have an argument like this: since it is a surjective homomorphism. the preimage has to be a proper subgroup. But if it is not maximal, the image of the maximal group containing the proper subgroup is still $M$. Thus the preimage has to be a maximal subgroup. But here I did not use the correspondence theorem, maybe there is some simpler argument?

Comment: The correspondence theorem says the lattice of subgroups of $G/N$ is isomorphic to the lattice of subgroups of $G$ that contain $N$ (by $H \mapsto H/N$). In particular, the maximal (proper) elements of these lattices agree

Comment: I see, $N=ker \phi$ here.

Comment: Yup! This is where we use surjectivity of $\theta$ ^_^

Comment: Also - if this answered your question, you should mark it as such by hitting the check mark next to it. This way other users know how to spend their time