# Intersection of all maximal subgroups of a finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups, maximal-subgroup

Let $G$ be a group. Define
$$F=\left\lbrace x\in G\;:\; \text{if } \left\langle S,x\right\rangle=G\text{ then }\left\langle S\right\rangle=G\right\rbrace.$$
I have that $F$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. In particular, if $G$ is finite, I have that $F$ is the intersection of all maximal subgroups of $G$. I have trouble showing that: If $G$ is a (finite) $p$-group ($p$ is a prime number), then every non-identity element of $G/F$ has order $p$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352331/frattini-subgroup-of-p-groups

Comment: You can show this directly: in a p-group (or any finite nilpotent group), every maximal subgroup is normal. What does that mean the quotient looks like?

Comment: You should specify $S$ in your definition. And look at the concept of Frattini subgroups.

Comment: $S$ is a subset of $G$, you can deduce that from the definition. If $S$ and $x$ form a generator for $G$, then $S$ generates $G$